# Facebook OAuth 2.0 / connect

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im starting to implement the Facebook apis into my website..

Where i am having trouble is understanding the oauth api. Maybe this inst the correct api?

Basically what i am trying to do is allow the user to sign in / register with Facebook and and storing that information in my database as a new user as i will be creating a profile from this. I would also like the user to be able to login with or without Facebook using his credentials. I understand he would have to create a password on my site. Is it practical to store his information .. Name Address email and other information.

I am very confused with the api and need help. reading through the documentation i cannot find where this explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at **[how to authenticate user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login)** using facebook login system on your website

About your question on storing emails, check facebook **[policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)** are mentioned here

Use [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) for accessing user details and other stuff

Hope this helps